# SQL Server CHOOSE() function behaving unexpectedly with RAND() function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, random, rounding

I've encountered an interesting SQL server behaviour while trying to generate random values in T-sql using [RAND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [CHOOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions.

My goal was to try to return one of two given values using RAND() as rng. Pretty easy right?

For those of you who don't know it, CHOOSE function accepts in an index number(int) along with a collection of values and returns a value at specified index. Pretty straightforward.

At first attempt my SQL looked like this:

```sql
    select choose(ceiling((rand()*2)) ,'a','b')
```

To my surprise, this expression returned one of three values: null, 'a' or 'b'. Since I didn't expect the null value i started digging. RAND() function returns a float in range from 0(included) to 1 (excluded). Since I'm multiplying it by 2, it should return values anywhere in range from 0(included) to 2 (excluded). Therefore after use of CEILING function final value should be one of: 0,1,2. After realising that i extended the value list by 'c' to check whether that'd be perhaps returned. I also checked the docs page of [CEILING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and learnt that:

> Return values have the same type as numeric_expression.

I assumed the CEILINGfunction returned int, but in this case would mean that the value is implicitly cast to int before being used in CHOOSE, which sure enough is stated on the docs page:

> If the provided index value has a numeric data type other than int,
> then the value is implicitly converted to an integer.

Just in case I added an explicit cast. My SQL query looks like this now:

```sql
    select choose(cast(ceiling((rand()*2)) as int) ,'a','b','c')
```

However, the result set didn't change. To check which values cause the problem I tried generating the value beforehand and selecting it alongside the CHOOSE result. It looked like this:

```sql
    declare @int int = cast(ceiling((rand()*2)) as int)
    select @int,choose( @int,'a','b','c')
```

Interestingly enough, now the result set changed to (1,a), (2,b) which was my original goal. After delving deeper in the CHOOSE docs page and some testing i learned that 'null' is returned in one of two cases:

1. Given index is a null
2. Given index is out of range

In this case that would mean that index value when generated inside the SELECT statement is either 0 or above 2/3 (I'm assuming that negative numbers are not possible here and CHOOSE function indexes from 1). As I've stated before 0 should be one of possibilities of:

```sql
    ceiling((rand()*2))
```

,but for some reason it's never 0 (at least when i tried it 1 million+ times like this)

```sql
    set nocount on
    
    declare @test table(ceiling_rand int)
    declare @counter int = 0
    
    while @counter<1000000
    begin
    insert into @test 
    select ceiling((rand()*2))
    
    set @counter=@counter+1
    end
    
    select distinct ceiling_rand from @test
```

Therefore I assume that the value generated in SELECT is greater than 2/3 or NULL. Why would it be like this only when generated in SELECT statement? Perhaps order of resolving CAST, CELING or RAND inside SELECT is different than it would seem? It's true I've only tried it a limited number of times, but at this point the chances of it being a statistical fluctuation are extremely small. Is it somehow a floating-point error? I truly am stumbled and looking forward to any explanation.

**TL;DR**: When generating a random number inside a SELECT statement result set of possible values is different then when it's generated before the SELECT statement.

Cheers,
NFSU

EDIT: Formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what's going on if you look at the execution plan.

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON

GO

SELECT (select choose(ceiling((rand()*2)) ,'a','b'))
```

Returns

```
  |--Constant Scan(VALUES:((CASE WHEN CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,ceiling(rand()*(2.0000000000000000e+000)),0)=(1) THEN 'a' ELSE CASE WHEN CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,ceiling(rand()*(2.0000000000000000e+000)),0)=(2) THEN 'b' ELSE NULL END END)))
```

The `CHOOSE` is expanded out to

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN ceiling(( rand() * 2 )) = 1 THEN 'a'
         ELSE
           CASE
             WHEN ceiling(( rand() * 2 )) = 2 THEN 'b'
             ELSE NULL
           END
       END
```

and `rand()` is referenced twice. Each evaluation can return a different result.

You will get the same problem with the below rewrite being expanded out too

```
  SELECT CASE ceiling(( rand() * 2 ))
         WHEN 1 THEN 'a'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'b'
       END
```

Avoid `CASE` for this and any of its variants.

One method would be

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE ( '["a", "b"]' , CONCAT('$[', FLOOR(rand()*2) ,']') )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was vastly insightful. If you don't mind me asking, would you perhaps also know the answer to why  ```ceiling(( rand() * 2 ))``` is never 0?

Comment: It could only be `0` if `rand()` was exactly zero. As `rand()` returns a result like `0.512158037153074` you would have to evaluate it a lot of times to expect the exact value zero to come up

Comment: "Returns a pseudo-random float value from 0 through 1, exclusive."   note the exclusive

Comment: @MartinSmith Allright. so it's just extremely unlikely, i guess somewhere in the range of 1 to 1.79E+308, somehow didn't cross my mind. Thank you for taking your time to answer :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Oh yeah, I must have misread that, luckily doesn't change the matter at hand, but thanks for your keen eye :)

Comment: yeah, seems to be conflicting information on the web as to whether the "exclusive" just applies to the `1` end but either way I'm not going to evaluate a load of random numbers to find out. So either not possible or very unlikely!